# Image set frame

Tags: swiftui

In the official tutorial of SwiftUI, I try to customize image to display the entire screen

The solution is to set the frame to a fixed width and height

```
struct CircleImage : View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("image01")
//            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(
                Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
            .shadow(radius: 10)   
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MapView()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                .frame(height: 300)
            CircleImage()
                .offset(y: -130)
                .padding(.bottom, -130)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Hello Maxwell!")
                    .font(.title)
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Text("Chaoyang Beijing")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("China")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
            }
            .padding()

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Why is the ContentView call.frame(width: 300, height: 300) invalid ?

Comment: what do you mean by "invalid"? Is the image frame not being set to 300x300? If that is the case, then that is to be expected.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming when you say "invalid" you mean the image is not resizing to the frame with width and height of 300. If so, your issue is that you are not making the image resizable. Update `CircleImage` to the code below and the image should resize.

```
struct CircleImage : View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("image01")
            .resizable() //add this line
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(
                Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
            .shadow(radius: 10)   
    }
}
```